# Show solutions to vector differential equation lie in plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I'm stuck on the last part of a question I'm working on and can't see a way through. I'm asked to show that the solutions to the differential equation $\mathbf{\ddot{x} + |\dot{x}|^{2}x=0}$ lie on a plane through the origin, where $\mathbf{x}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ is a curve constrained to lie on the sphere $S^{2} = \left \{ \boldsymbol{x}:\boldsymbol{|x|}=1 \right \}$
 if that's relevant (ie show the solutions are great circles). Could somebody give me a clue as to how to proceed? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could try showing that the geodesic curvature of any solution is 0, since the set of geodesics on the sphere is exactly the set of great circles.

Comment: Differentiate cross product $ x X \dot x =$  constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's find the torsion: we know that $ \ddot{x} + \lVert \dot{x} \rVert^2 x=0 $. Dotting with $x$ and $\dot{x}$ gives
$$ x \cdot \ddot{x} + \lVert \dot{x} \rVert^2 = 0 \\
\dot{x} \cdot \ddot{x} = 0, $$
because $x \cdot x = 1$, and so $ x \cdot \dot{x} = 0$.

Differentiating again,
$$ 0 = \dddot{x}+2(\dot{x} \cdot \ddot{x}) x + \lVert \dot{x} \rVert ^2 \dot{x} = \dddot{x} + \lVert \dot{x} \rVert ^2 \dot{x}. $$

Now, the torsion is given by the formula
$$ \kappa^2 \tau = (\dot{x} \times \ddot{x}) \cdot \dddot{x} = \lVert \dot{x} \rVert^4 (\dot{x} \times x) \cdot \dot{x} = 0,  $$
by the above, and using that $a \times b$ is perpendicular to $a$ and $b$. The curvature is nonzero because $\kappa = \lVert \ddot{x} \rVert =  \lVert \dot{x} \rVert^2 $ using the original equation. Hence the torsion is zero, and the curve is planar.

Comment: Completely forgot about torsion, that's perfect, thanks a lot.